# Passing Date object is prop in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, datejs

I'm trying to pass a date object as a prop in react native, and access its methods to render data.

The prop is passed as following:

```
 <Task
                  text={item["text"]}
                  date={item["date"]}
                  time={item["time"]}
                  reminder={item["reminder"]}
                  completed={item["completed"]}
                />
```

It is accessed as:

```
<View>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.item,
          completed
            ? { backgroundColor: "#98CBB4" }
            : { backgroundColor: "#CCC9DC" },
        ]}
      >
        <View style={styles.ciricleTitle}>
          <View style={styles.circular}></View>
          <Text style={styles.itemText}>{text}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{console.log(date.date)}</Text>
        {/* <Text style={styles.itemText}>{date.getDay()}</Text> */}
      </View>
      {completed && <View style={styles.line} />}
    </View>
```

i tried expanding the prop with `{...item['date']}` but it is not working

Comment: Can you please confirm if the item["date"] infact a date object and not a stringified time value. If it is, then new Date(item["date"] should work.

Comment: turns out it is a string, is there a way to convert it back to a object?

Comment: Just a tip: unless the `item` object is really huge, I would recommend passing the whole `item` as a prop, and then get the individual properties inside the Task component using `{props.item.text}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have to convert string to date object, You can use `new Date(date).getDay()`

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify your doubt first.

1. sending *date which is a string* as a prop
2. sending *date which is an object* as a prop

So, you have made the mistake here. You have sent the date string rather than as the date object and trying to access the properties.

```
<div>
 {
  itemList.map(({ text, date, time, reminder, completed }) => (
   <Task {...{ text, date, time, reminder, completed }} />
  ))
 }
</div>
```

The **date** you are passing here undoubtedly is a string(which is **item.date**)

One way to acheive what you want is, send it as a date object..

```
<Task
 {...{
  text,
  time,
  reminder,
  completed,
  date: new Date(date)
 }}
/>
```

So that,

```
<Text style={styles.itemText}>{date.getDay()}</Text>
```

would become valid.